Is there an HTML5 API to control camera focus and zoom on iPhone?
I am currently working on a web application that requires the ability to control the camera's focus and zoom directly from the browser. The application is designed to be used on iPhones, and I am looking for a solution that works specifically on iOS devices.
Here are the specific requirements and constraints:
Platform: The solution must work on iPhones running the latest version of iOS.
Browser: It should be compatible with Safari, as it is the default browser on iOS.
Functionality: The API or method must allow us to:
Control the camera's focus manually.
Adjust the zoom level programmatically.
I have explored the standard getUserMedia API, but it seems to lack direct control over focus and zoom functionalities. I've also looked into various JavaScript libraries, but haven't found one that meets these specific needs.
Has anyone successfully implemented camera focus and zoom control on an iPhone using HTML5, JavaScript, or any other web technologies? If so, could you please share the approach or any resources that might help?
Thank you for your assistance!

I believe you're looking for a way to zoom in and zoom out using MediaStreamTrack: getCapabilities() method.

And I have the apt solution for you in that case. Recently, I made an Advanced Camera JS (a modular JS vanilla web app) to capture photos and videos (along with a BeReal kind of dual mode to take a picture from both front and rare camera almost simultaneously).
Check the zoom feature using the demo here: https://cybtekk-llp.github.io/Advanced-Camera/
and here is the codebase: https://github.com/CybTekk-LLP/Advanced-Camera/ (Remove any code for direct download and use in the way you want).
Now I am adding some code so I can explain the core functionality:
export const streamWebCamVideo = (isFrontCamera = true) => {
  const video = document.getElementById("stream");
  const constraints = {
    video: {
      facingMode: isFrontCamera ? "user" : "environment", // Toggle between front and rear cameras
      zoom: true,
    },
  };
  window.navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
        isFrontCamera && video.classList.add("flip");
        !isFrontCamera && video.classList.remove("flip");
        video.play();
      };
      const [track] = stream.getVideoTracks();
      const capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
      const settings = track.getSettings();

      const input = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

      // Check whether zoom is supported or not.
      if (!("zoom" in settings)) {
        return Promise.reject("Zoom is not supported by " + track.label);
      }

      // Map zoom to a slider element.
      input.min = capabilities.zoom.min;
      input.max = capabilities.zoom.max;
      input.step = capabilities.zoom.step;
      input.value = settings.zoom;

      document.querySelector(".zoom-multiplier").textContent = `${~~capabilities
        .zoom.min}x ${
        ~~(capabilities.zoom.max + 3 * capabilities.zoom.min) / 4
      }x ${
        ~~(3 * capabilities.zoom.max + capabilities.zoom.min) / 4
      }x ${~~capabilities.zoom.max}x`;

      console.log("min:", capabilities.zoom.min);
      console.log("max:", capabilities.zoom.max);
      console.log("step:", capabilities.zoom.step);
      console.log("value:", settings.zoom);

      input.oninput = function (event) {
        track.applyConstraints({ advanced: [{ zoom: event.target.value }] });
        document.querySelector(".slider").style.left =
          ((input.value - 1) * 120) / (capabilities.zoom.max - 1) + 3 + "px";
      };
      input.hidden = false;
      document.querySelector(".range-container").style.visibility = "visible";
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
};

I have taken the zoom capability level and attached it to an input type="range" so one can use the slider to adjust camera zoom level.
IF this still doesn't help, let me know more about your problem.
Edit: also for the focus part, check this out: Use the focusMode constraint to get required media device

Hope you are doing well,
Directly controlling the camera's focus and zoom via standard web technologies on iOS is currently limited. The most viable solutions involve either creating a native iOS app with web integration or using hybrid frameworks that allow deeper access to device capabilities.
Greetings
